# How to remove a box in pygame if users input 0 in another file?

Tags: python, input, pygame, user-input

Ok so I am very new to coding and this is my first project. For a psychology study I have to create a game board (that looks like a jeopardy board) with different prompts in each box (i.e., wants children, cat attitudes). I have the game basically created so that both members of a couple complete a questionnaire in file 1, where the responses are recorded using file write to file 2. Lastly, in the game board file (file 3), they have the option of clicking on a box to see what their partners response was to a specific question. However, while individuals are filling out the questionnaire in file 1, they have the option to input '0' indicating that they don't feel comfortable answering. Is there a way for me to program the gameboard so that if someone doesn't want to answer a question in file 1, the box disappears in file 3? Sorry if this is confusing! Here is my code for file 3. File 1 just takes the input from the questionaire and writes it to file 2. File 2 is just a list of those responses.

```
import pygame, sys, linecache, time
from pygame.locals import*
pygame init()

start_time = time.time()

black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)
pink = (255,200,200)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400, 600)
pygame.display.set_caption("Getting to know you project")
screen.fill(black)

while True:
    for event in pygame.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        end = time.time() - start
        print("Selection took you " + str(end) + "seconds. \n")
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 0], [1400, 0], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 200], [1400, 200], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 400], [1400, 400], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 600], [1400, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 0], [1200, 0], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [200, 0], [200, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [400, 0], [400, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [600, 0], [600, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [800, 0], [800, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [1200, 0], [1200, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 0], [0, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [1000, 0], [1000, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [1400, 0], [1400, 600], 5)

    sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 30)
    rendered = sys_font.render('Wants Marriage', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered, (20, 40))
    rendered2 = sys_font.render('Religiosity', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered2, (40, 240))
    rendered3 = sys_font.render('Political', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered3, (55, 440))
    rendered4 = sys_font.render('Wants Children', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered4, (230, 40))
    rendered5 = sys_font.render('Likely to Move', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered5, (230, 240))
    rendered6 = sys_font.render('Away', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered6, (265, 260))
    rendered7 = sys_font.render('Urban/Rural', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered7, (240, 440))
    rendered8 = sys_font.render('Preferences', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered8, (240, 460))
    rendered9 = sys_font.render('Importance of Sex', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered9, (420, 40))
    rendered10 = sys_font.render('Ideal Sex', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered10, (450, 240))
    rendered11 = sys_font.render('Frequency', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered11, (440, 260))
    rendered12 = sys_font.render('Importance of', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered12, (435, 440))
    rendered14 = sys_font.render('Orientation', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered14, (30, 460))
    rendered15 = sys_font.render('Alcohol', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered15, (665, 40))
    rendered16 = sys_font.render('Frequency', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered16, (650, 60))
    rendered17 = sys_font.render('Hobbies', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered17, (660, 240))
    rendered18 = sys_font.render('Marijuana', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered18, (650, 440))
    rendered19 = sys_font.render('Frequency', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered19, (645, 460))
    rendered20 = sys_font.render('Novelty', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered20, (860, 40))
    rendered21 = sys_font.render('Seeking', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered21, (860, 60))
    rendered22 = sys_font.render('Activity Level', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered22, (835, 240))
    rendered23 = sys_font.render('Jealousy', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered23, (850, 440))
    rendered24 = sys_font.render('Communication', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered24, (1030, 40))
    rendered25 = sys_font.render('Financial Style', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered25, (1030, 240))
    rendered26 = sys_font.render('Division of', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered26, (1040, 440))
    rendered27 = sys_font.render('Household Labor', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered27, (1020, 460))
    rendered28 = sys_font.render('Home Tidiness', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered28, (1230, 40))
    rendered29 = sys_font.render('Cat Attitudes', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered29, (1230, 240))
    rendered30 = sys_font.render('Dog Attitudes', 0, (80, 200, 80))
    screen.blit(rendered30, (1230, 440))
    Rectplace = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (60, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (60, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (60, 500, 60, 60))
    Rect4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (280, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (280, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect6 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (280, 500, 60, 60))
    Rect7 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (480, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect8 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (480, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect9 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (480, 500, 60, 60))
    Rect10 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (680, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect11 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (680, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect12 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (680, 500, 60, 60))
    Rect13 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (880, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect14 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (880, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect15 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (880, 500, 60, 60))
    Rect16 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (1080, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect17 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (1080, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect18 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (1080, 500, 60, 60))
    Rect19 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (1280, 100, 60, 60))
    Rect20 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (1280, 300, 60, 60))
    Rect21 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (1280, 500, 60, 60))
    pygame.display.update()
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pressed1, pressed2, pressed3 = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if Rectplace.collidepoint(pos) and pressed1:
        marriage = linecache.getline("Responses.txt", 7)
        print("To the question, \"Do you plan on getting married someday?\"\n 1 = Definitely not \n 2 = Probably not \n 3 = Maybe/Unsure \n 4 = Probably \n 5 = Definitely,\n your partner responded:  ")
        print(marriage)
        input("How important to you is your partner's response to this question?: ")
    if Rect2.collidepoint(pos) and pressed1:
        religion = linecache.getline("Responses.txt", 10)
        print("To the question, \"What is your religious affiliation\" \n Buddhist \n Catholic \n Hindu \n Muslim \n Protestant \n Latter-day Saint \n Not Religious/Atheist/Agnostic \n Other \n, your partner responded:  ")
        print(religion)
    if Rect3.collidepoint(pos) and pressed1:
        print("To the question, \"On a scale from 1 (Very Conservative) to 7 (Very Liberal),what is your political orientation?\", your parter responded:  ")
        politics = linecache.getline("Responses.txt", 11)
        print(politics)
    if Rect4.collidepoint(pos) and pressed1:
        children = linecache.getline("Responses.txt", 8)
        print(children)
    if Rect5.collidepoint(pos) and pressed1:
        move = linecache.getline("Responses.txt", 9)
        print(move)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimalistic reproducible code with your question.

Comment: Sorry, added my code for file 3! File 1 is just a questionnaire that takes the input and writes it to file 2. File 2 is just a list of the individuals answers!

Comment: To achieve what you want given your current code, you would need to rework the code from the top. Especially the draw functions. You can make a custom function to draw the entries for each box. However, this will change your code almost completely. You may also want to read on **OOP** for further clarifications.

Comment: if it makes it easier, would it possible for the box to just show up empty?

Comment: Yes. If you add and if-else clause before the draw function, checking if the value in your file 2 is 0, then you can choose to or not to draw a box's content.

Answer (score 0):

This very easily solved by using the 'if' function for the whole loop. Also, you should automate the part for setting variables and calling inputs

it would be something like this

```
for n in range(0,s):
    if returned_value != '0':
        input value
        rendered[n] = sys_font.render('text', 0, (80, 200, 80))
        screen.blit(rendered, (x, y))
```